# validation for login page from website database for android app

Tags: android

I'm new to android, please can anybody help me here, how to validate username and password from the website database where only the registered user can only login. How to fetch specific content from my website and display it in android app.

Answer (score 2):

See in an app there are two types of validations

`1. Client side validation and 2. Server side validation`

Here you asking about server side Login authentication for Android App. Please refer this [Link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/) it is great solution what you finding. In this tutorial exactly described what you searching.

Comment: my website had been designed on wordpress, so could not find sql database for username and password validation...

Comment: just clarify please you have android client and as backend wordpress ?

Answer (score 0):

you Used DbAdpter Class.my code in below:

```
public class DBAdpter {
    public static String url = YourServerlink;

    public static String loginInUser(String username, String password) {
        String result = "";
        String msg = "";
        InputStream is = null;

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

        try {
            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url + "login.php?");
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        }
        // convert response to string
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString().trim();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        try {
            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(result);
            msg = jObj.getString("Message");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return msg;
    }
```

And you used login page put my code below on create method:

```
            uname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user_edt_lg);
        pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pass_edt_lg);
        login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
        reg_txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.reg_txt);
        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                strUname = uname.getText().toString().trim();
                strPass = pass.getText().toString().trim();
                DBAdpter.loginInUser(strUname, strPass);
                Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Successfully login", 1)
                        .show();

                Intent i = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, All_Quiz_list.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });
```

Comment: server link means website address??

Answer (score 0):

this is good example for user login from web server..

[1. Login Application For Android](http://wowjava.wordpress.com/2011/01/16/login-application-for-android/)

Comment: i followed this link only, but getting error in... public static String executeHttpGet("String url") throws Exception

Comment: i gave my website address in place of url, i followed this link http://wowjava.wordpress.com/2011/01/16/login-application-for-android/

Comment: url means my website address?